# Controlling ongoing test in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

If I have already started test with N number of test-cases using TestNG,

- How can I skip some of the test-cases in the run time?
- How can I abort the testing gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I skip some of the test-cases in the run time?

TestNG lets you skip Tests by having your `@Test` methods throw a `org.testng.SkipException`. So within your `@Test` methods, you can build the logic of checking for some runtime condition (perhaps via a JVM argument and then have this exception thrown accordingly).

> How can I abort the testing gracefully?

Unless you explicitly invoke `System.exit()` from within your `@Test` methods or TestNG listeners, all TestNG executions end only gracefully. There's nothing you need to do extra.